# Динамическое добавление элементов в PopupMenu

Tags: delphi, события

Как добавлять элементы меню динамически, например похожие слова из словаря `dict.txt`, желательно с событием, заменяющим выделенное слово на словарное?

```
procedure TForm1.PopupMenu1Popup(Sender: TObject);
    var
      search, dictItem: AnsiString;
      pitem: TMenuItem;
      l, r, j: integer;
    begin
      PopupMenu1:=PopupMenu1.Create(RichEdit1);
      PopupMenu1.Items.Clear;
      search:=Trim(RichEdit1.SelText);
      if (RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color <> clRed) or (RichEdit1.SelLength < 2) then exit;

      AssignFile(input, 'dict.txt');
      reset(input);
      while not(eof(input)) do
      begin
        readln(dictItem);
        if LeveDist(dictItem, search) < 3 then
        begin
          pitem:=TMenuItem(PopupMenu1);
          pitem.Caption:=dictItem;
          PopupMenu1.Items.Add(pitem);
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это ведь так просто гуглится. Вариант **первый**:

```
Item := TMenuItem.Create(PopupMenu1);
Item.Caption := 'First Menu';
Item.OnClick := MenuItem1Click;
PopupMenu1.Items.Add(Item);
```

Вариант **второй**:

```
PopUpMenu1.Items.Add(
    NewItem('First Menu', 0, False, True, MenuItem1Click, 0, 'MenuItem1')
);
```

По поводу же **замены** на слово. Его вы вписываете в `Caption` элемента? Тогда можно получить заголовок нажатого пункта меню, обратившись к `Sender`. Если я ничего не забыл, то:

```
Word = (Sender as TMenuItem).Caption; // внутри процедуры Menuitem1Click
```

**Ссылки**:

- [Как динамически создавать пункты подменю в PopupMenu](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/create_popup_menu_items.html)
- [A Better Way to Create Menu Items](http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=48268)

Comment: спасибо, уже сделал :)

Comment: Тут вам ответили про гугл, зацените: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436125/181472 =)

Answer (score 0):

```
chStr:=dictItem;
popupmenu1.items.Add(NewItem(dictItem, 0, False, True, AClick, 0, 'MenuItem2'));
```

при этом в AClick заменяю RichEdit1.SelText на значение глобальной переменной chStr